# HttpContext from System.Web.UI.Page?

Tags: asp.net

Given an instance of a System.Web.UI.Page, is there any way to get the current HttpContext from it?  There is a protected Context property, but I'm hoping for something exposed publicly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access the current context from anywhere with

```
HttpContext.Current
```

Comment: This isn't thread-safe though, as `HttpContext.Current`'s value depends on the thread being used to access it. If you want to pass a `Page` object to another thread for some reason then you'll run into problems because `HttpContext.Current` may return `null` or a different request's `HttpContext` (if a thread is being reused in a thread-pool).

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it via `RequestContext` which is a public property. Though it returns `HttpContextBase` instead of `HttpContext` but that should be fine for most applications.

```
public static HttpContextBase GetHttpContext( this System.Web.UI.Page page )
{
    if( page == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(page));
    return page.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext;
}
```

As it's an extension method, you only need to do:

```
Page page = ... // Get `page` instance from somewhere.
page.GetHttpContext().Response.WriteLine("working!");
```